# Does DynamoDBContext Have support for pooling?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working with DynamoDBContext and I am in a stage where I want to introduce parallelism.

Since I will be making db calls I thought I need to manage a connection pool so that when I am done that I could release it and try to avoid hitting maximum throttle.

Is there a way to implement this? I have not been able to find anything in AWS docs and I am hoping to get some help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get throttled by having too many connections in DynamoDB, you can create as many as you like and it won't matter. The SDK's handle pooling by default for you, but its not quite the same as connection pools for relational databases.

What you're looking for is [ConnectionLimit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/P_Amazon_Runtime_ClientConfig_ConnectionLimit.htm) which you place in the services config.

Comment: Is there a way to modify it? Like lets say max pool size?